# Как из кода убрать Service из автозагрузки?

Tags: android, service

В приложении Android запускается служба. В манифесте запрашивается пермишн RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, тут же описан receiver с intent-filter: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED. В коде самого receiver в onReceive запускается Service. Таким образом она попадает в автозагрузку. Собственно, вопрос: как из кода убрать этот Service из автозагрузки?

Comment: удалить из кода строку, запускающую сервис

Comment: @metalurgus Кэп, серьезно?

Comment: А что не так? Логично же, Чтобы убрать что-то из кода, нужно просто это удалить из кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда нужно будет убрать срвис из автозагрузки, запишите в `SharedPreferences` `boolean` флаг со значением `false`, и в `receiver` проверяйте этот флаг. Если он `false`, то не стартуйте сервис.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отключить ненужный компонент (Receiver например):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, Receiver.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    componentName,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```